# Google API Python Client Firebase App Distribution HTTP 400

Tags: python, firebase, google-api-python-client, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying to list my builds that I have uploaded to Firebase App Distribution with the help of the [google-api-python-client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/firebaseappdistribution_v1.html) however I always get a HTTP status code 400.

I have created a `service-account.json` with full owner rights (for testing)
I have copied my `project_id` from Firebase Console.
I have copied my `app_id` from Firebase Console.

My Python script:

```py
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
service_account_file = os.path.join(script_dir, 'service-account.json')
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file)

project_id = credentials.project_id
app_id = "1:310501947997:android:4f5183af1eddc4004eabb4"

service = build('firebaseappdistribution', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

try:
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/apps/{app_id}"
    app_releases = service.projects().apps().releases().list(parent=parent).execute()
    print(app_releases)
except HttpError as e:
    print('Error response status code : {0}, reason : {1}'.format(e.status_code, e.error_details))
```

> Error response status code : 400, reason : Request contains an invalid argument.

Does somebody have any pointers on what argument is invalid which is causing the HTTP 400?

Comment: I think the problem is with the parent. You are using the Project ID but the documentation specifies Project Number: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/firebaseappdistribution_v1.projects.apps.releases.html#list

Comment: You are correct! Please post this as an answer. I want to reward you with some internet points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using the `Project ID`. The API requires specifying the `Project Number`.

> parent: string, Required. The name of the app resource, which is the
> parent of the release resources. Format:
> `projects/{project_number}/apps/{app_id}` (required)

Refer to this documentation for more details on the required parameters:

[projects().apps().releases().list()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/firebaseappdistribution_v1.projects.apps.releases.html#list)